# Npm throws error while installing a package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm developing a reactjs project and could add any package using npm. All of a sudden npm installer began to throw error for any package installation. The error is same for all packages. I removed and reinstalled Nodejs, but the error is there as a rock.

Error:

[image: npm install error]

Error log:

[image: npm install error log]

Any idea to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you post the log and not just a screenshot? Looks like those weird question mark characters are causing your error.

Comment: It's because of the file encoding of one of your project `.js` file. Delete the file and create it again using notepad. That will fix the issue. The question mark characters on `line 10` are causing those errors.

Comment: @MattOestreich the log file is exactly same as screenshot, i checked it again. But if you think its necessary, i'll upload it.

Comment: @Utkarsh If it's because of the file encoding, so 1) how can i find which file is wrong encoded; 2) why this issue occurs when i want to install a new package and the project itself is compiled and run correctly?

Comment: I was just curious what the full path to the problem file was.. Try removing `cli-table-3` from the specified path in `AppData`... looks like a file in that package is causing this issue.

Comment: do you mean i have a package installed as **cli-table-3** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cli-table3 is the source of issue. I think this package is installed and used by `Node.js` itself to be able to display table format in console. I uninstalled the `Node.js` and then deleted `npm` and `npm-cache` folders of the path `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming` - Of course i didn't have any global package installed. Then reinstalling `Node.js` solved the issue.